# find line, replace multiple lines

Tags: text, python

There are many threads on find replace text for python but I think my question is different.

I have a bunch of java files with

```
System.out.println("some text here");
```

I am trying to write a python script which will replace them all with

```
if (logger.isInfoEnabled()) {
    logger.info("some text here");
}
```

To do this I have tried:

```
def findReplace(fileName, sourceText, replaceText):
    file = open(fileName, "r") #Opens the file in read-mode
    text = file.read() #Reads the file and assigns the value to a variable
    file.close() #Closes the file (read session)

    file = open(fileName, "w") #Opens the file again, this time in write-mode
    file.write(text.replace(sourceText, replaceText)) #replaces all instances of our keyword
    # and writes the whole output when done, wiping over the old contents of the file
    file.close() #Closes the file (write session)
```

and pass in:

```
filename=Myfile.java, sourceText='System.out.println', replaceText='if (logger.isInfoEnabled()) { \n' \logger.info'
```

However, I am struggling to the get the closing ' in the replace.  It needs to wrap out around the same output string that is already there. Any tips?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import re

sourceText = 'System\.out\.println\(("[^"]+")\);'

replaceText = \
r'''if (logger.isInfoEnabled()) {
    logger.info(\1);
}'''

re.sub(sourceText, replaceText, open(fileName).read())
```

This isn't perfect -- it will only work if the string doesn't contain any escaped quote marks i.e. `\"` -- but hopefully it should do the trick.

Comment: You can use r'''System\.out\.println\("(.+?)(?="\);)"\);''' to lazily take all characters up until the closing sequence "); which should accommodate any escaped quotes within.

Comment: Sure, a lazy search solves the problem partially (although I'm not sure the lookahead is really necessary?). There's always then the problem that the string contains `\";)` though.

Comment: @bluepnume when I try your's I am told there is too many parenthesis.  Sorry I am not good at regular expressions, any tips?

Comment: dublintech: sorry about that, small typo. Fixed now.

Answer (score 3):

You will certainly have trouble with that, because doing replacements around matching delimiters is hard. One approach that makes way more sense to me -- for more reasons than one -- is to define a new java function `log_if_enabled`, and then just replace `System.out.println` with `log_if_enabled`. That way, you don't have to worry about doing any fancy brace matching. Also, encapsulating the `if` statement in a function is DRY.

Comment: No that won't work.  You need to check if log4j is enabled before any string concatenation see: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html section performance.

Comment: @dublintech: What senderle is saying is that you should write the new `log_if_enabled` function (or whatever you want to name it) so that *it* does the check.  That is, your `if` statement should be in this new function.

Comment: Yeah but by that stage the concatenation has happened and the damage done.  It would be invoked as log_if_enable("my output=" + output + ", at this server=" + servername);  This approach only works if you are never concatenating. You usually are when you are logging.

Comment: @dublintech, ah, I see what you mean. It's not that it won't work, it's just not quite as efficient. Well, since I don't know the specifics of your situation, I won't accuse you of [premature optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization). I'll just sneakily insert a reference to it, just in case :)

Comment: @senderis ha.  Are people who use arraylists instead of vectors also engaging in premature optimisation :-) ?